# Undefined control sequence on \frac?

Tags: math-mode, pgfplots, graphs

I'd like to generate PDF's for some ad hoc screenshots, but I'm getting an undefined control error. I tried `\usepackage{amsmath}` after the line `\usepackage{pgfplots}` but that didn't work. I thought maybe that package was required for use of `\frac{x}{2}`

I'm using TeXworks with the following to try and generate a generic plot of `x/2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,xmax=10,
        ymin=-10,ymax=10,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,<->] expression[domain=-10:10,samples=100]{\frac{x}{2}} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\frac{x}{2}$}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error is on the `node` line 16 I believe, but I can't tell if it's syntax or otherwise.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 

l.16 ...=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\frac{x}{2}$};
```

Please consider me very new to LaTeX. I guess I'm assuming there is a missing package, since I can successfully plot simple linear graphs that don't include `\frac`.

Comment: I realized as I was reading John's answer that the node was the annotation and *should* use `\frac` while the plot should be the generic expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write `x/2` instead of `\frac{x}{2}`.

- In the *equation* of the graph, you want a mathematical expression that PGFplots can understand. The syntax for division in PGFplots is simply `/`.
- In the *label* for the graph, you just want a piece of text, so `y=\frac{x}{2}` is fine here.

### Fixed code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,xmax=10,
        ymin=-10,ymax=10,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,<->] expression[domain=-10:10,samples=100]{x/2} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\frac{x}{2}$}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see--the node is the annotation which is essentially *text* while the addplot is the expression.